# AWS Amplify with Amazon Cognito not remembering device with hosted UI

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I want to be able to remember a user's device using Amplify's hosted UI with React. I set up MFA as required in the user pool. In "devices" I set **Do you want to remember your user's devices?** to "User-Opt In"  and **Do you want to use a remembered device to suppress the second factor during multi-factor authentication (MFA)?** to "Yes". In the React side I'm using the withAuthenticator HOC.

The problem is when I login, I get redirected to the confirm sms code page without the application or amplifying remembering the device. Also if I look at the device in the user pool, it has the status: note_remembered.

Is there any way to configure this through the hosted Amplify UI and if not how would I do it programatically?

I looked through all the docs and don't see anything even though this seems like a pretty ubiquitous use case.

Answer (score 1):

It has been a while since I developed an Authentication Engine using Amplify. After going through the official Amplify Auth [documentation](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/authentication) and several Github threads, I was unable to find any API or technique to implement Cognito's Device remember feature.

In this case, I would recommend using a hybrid approach and using the [GetDevice](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#getDevice-property), [ConfirmDevice](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#confirmDevice-property), and [UpdateDeviceStatus](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#updateDeviceStatus-property) API calls in the native AWS JavaScript SDK, as the functionality is completely supported there.

Apropos which, Amplify is lacking a lot of imperative Cognito features, and I would implore you to raise a support request with the concerned AWS team.